# Problems with using ftp connection in Windows 8 - Server Vsftpd Centos

Tags: windows-8, ftp, centos

I have a problem with FTP connection in Windows 8 to my own server (Centos 6 with Vsftpd). All programs that i use (PSPad, Aptana3, File Zilla etc.) are connecting well but i can't edit files, or create them. I can only open folders and files. I have firewall disabled in Windows 8. My second laptop with Windows XP is working great with that server so i don't think it's a permission/firewall problem.
Thing is more complicated cause i can work normally on other ftp servers with my Windows 8. Is it possible that it's a Centos vsftpd configuration problem, so ONLY Windows 8 can't connect ?

Comment: could it be permission problem inside a Windows ? for example unable to create temp file in %TEMP% or in program files? Not sure how those programs work but i would aim in this direction. Did this worked in Windows 7?

Comment: Yes, it worked in Windows 7, and i have almost no knowledge about Windows 8 and it's permission